# Changing the value of a struct that is @Binding causes the child view to be dismissed as the parent view updates

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My goal is to have an array of structs that when tapped on an individual item, a change is made and passed up to the parent view but doesn't automatically dismiss my child view.  I'm really not sure why the child view is automatically dismissing and how to prevent it.  Here is my code for the ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

struct Person: Hashable {
    var name: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var patients: [Person]
    init() {
        var temp: [Person] = []
        for index in 0 ..< 3 {
            temp.append(Person(name: "\(index)"))
        }
        patients = temp
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
                ForEach($patients, id:\.self) { $patient in
                    NavigationLink("\(patient.name)") {
                        ChangeNameView(patient: $patient)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChangeNameView: View {
    @Binding var patient: Person
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            patient.name = "New Name"
        } label: {
            Text("Set New Name")
        }
    }
}
```

Tapping on a name will bring up the child view as expected.  Then tapping the button to change the name does so, but then immediately dismisses the view.

Comment: I'd love to know where people are learning this huge mistake of id:\.self from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that `Person` is `Hashable` (which only uses the `name` property) and for your `ForEach`, you're using `\.self` for the `id`.

SwiftUI's `ForEach` uses that `id:` parameter to keep track of which element is which in the list. Because you're using `\.self` and then *changing* the `name` of that element in `ChangeNameView`, it no longer looks like the same element and SwiftUI removes the child view from the hierarchy (since the old one doesn't exist in the list anymore).

One solution is to use truly `Identifiable` elements, where the `id` is unique and doesn't update when you change the `name`:

```
struct Person: Hashable, Identifiable { //<-- Here
    var id = UUID() //<-- Here
    var name: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var patients: [Person]
    init() {
        var temp: [Person] = []
        for index in 0 ..< 3 {
            temp.append(Person(name: "\(index)"))
        }
        patients = temp
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
                ForEach($patients) { $patient in //<-- Here -- when the items are Identifiable, it's essentially like saying `id: \.id`
                    NavigationLink("\(patient.name)") {
                        ChangeNameView(patient: $patient)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, makes total sense.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @KevinMcQuown can I ask why you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: I am running into an issue that has now resurfaced with the same behavior if it is a second level deep in the navigation hierarchy.  I want to repost my code but it won't fit in this comment area. When I try to edit my original post with code I get an error saying the edit queue is full.

Comment: I'll just create a new issue so I can post the code.

Comment: Okay -- I'm happy to take a look at a new issue, but it would be good if you would consider accepting this answer, as it directly explains and fixes the problem you presented in the original question.

Comment: done! :-). And posted my new code.

Comment: plz share link to your other question. As above solution didn't help me.